# Hide item template in aspx page based on condition

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I have following item template in my listview

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="ibtnEdit" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="20px" ToolTip="Edit  this Category" CommandArgument='<%#  Eval("Category_ID")  %>' CommandName="EditObject"  CausesValidation="False"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

I want to hide this column based on following condition. This status field contain either 1 or 0.

```
<%#    Bind("Status") %>
```

I am not getting an idea how to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with following code and it works

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="ibtnEdit" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="20px" ToolTip="Edit  this Category"
                        CommandArgument='<%#  Eval("Category_ID")  %>' Visible='<%# DecideHere((int)Eval("Status")) %>'  CommandName="EditObject"
                        CausesValidation="False"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton>
```

In code behind

```
 protected bool DecideHere(int id)
             {
                if (id == 1 )
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

@aniltc Do you also want to make it visible basing on the condition 0 and 1?

Try This, but not tested, logic will be similar I believe:

```
    if (txt_Status.Text != "")
        {
            string a, b;
                a=0;
                b=1;
        if (txt_Status.Text==a)
                    {

                        LinkButton lnkEdit = [YourDatalist].FindControl("ibtnEdit") as LinkButton;
                        lnkEdit.Visible = false;
                    }
         else if (txt_Status.Text == b)
                    {

                        LinkButton lnkEdit = [YourDatalist].FindControl("ibtnEdit") as LinkButton;
                        lnkEdit.Visible = true
                      }

           }
```

Comment: yes. If status is '1' then show item template else disable. Hope you got my point. Thanks

Comment: @aniltc okay first you need to make your itemtemplate visible property as false visible="false" then get the status value in textbox, and use if else statement to make your itemtemplate visible or hide.

Comment: @aniltc I have updated my answer kindly check. It is not tested but the logic will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the Visible property on the link button like this:

```
Visible='<%# Iif(Eval("Status")=1,True,False) %>'
```

Note you want to use Eval not Bind to do a one way data read.